# Call member function on object vector

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, foreach, std

Given a `vector<Object>`, where Object has a function `run()`, is there a way to call `run()` in a `for_each`, using only std functions/templates?

Note that `run()` is not a static function, it should actually transform the object being referenced (of course it's not the case in my small example)

I know the `boost::lambda` way

```
class Object
{
public:
    int run(){/* change object state */}
};

vector<Object> v(10);
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bind(&Object::run, _1));
```

but I am curious if it's a standard (**non-Cxx11**) way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is (was) C++03 way:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Object::run));
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun_ref/

Comment: Quick! btw, on VS2010 it only compiles with `mem_fun_ref(&Object::run)`

Comment: My mistake - I did not try and it was long time I was used this :(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, here is a more detailed example on how to use for_each

```
class Object
{
public:
    int run(){/* change object state */}
    int run2(char c){/* change object state */}
};

vector<Object> v(10);
char c = 'a';
```

If you want to send a parameter to your function (at max one, for C++03), you can

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind2nd( std::mem_fun_ref(&Object::run2), c));
```

Note that you bind the second argument. The first one is a `this` pointer to the current object. Did you remember that any member function always takes `this` as first parameter?

And the lambda way (C++11) **so much nicer!**

```
for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), [&] (const Object& val)
{
    val.run();  
    // this is effectively the most flexible way to specify the function params
    val.run2(c); 
} );
```

Finally, the **boost::lambda** way, for the situation when you have an argument.
As for the C++11, it is easy extendable to more parameters

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bind(&Holder::run, _1, c) );
```

Comment: Your lambda needs to capture c. Plus I would argue that the C++11 way would be a range based for loop and not std::for_each! :)

Comment: C++11 variable capture fixed. Thanks!